# Specify line length in Google Slides

Tags: google-slides

Is there a way to specify the length of a line or an arrow or whatever in Google Slides?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use the rectangle, you can set the width 0.01 inch while set the height as you want. It looks like a line.